# Use @ symbol in the text for string resource in android

Tags: android

I am trying to insert a "@" symbol at the beginning of a text field in android. I have specified that in the string resources file as

```
<string name="email_ext">@xyz.com</string>
```

But it throws a compiler error - "No resource type specified (at 'email_ext' with value '@xyz.com'). Is there a way to fix this? I have tried to set that using the setter, but I have different resource files for different languages. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add \

```
<string name="email_ext">\@xyz.com</string>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a `\` before that `@`

```
<string name="email_ext">\@xyz.com</string>
```

The reason is that an @ is the open symbol of any reference across Android resources. You could point to a color using `@color/white`, if you defined it. Because of this, the compiler tries to allocate a resource named xyz.com, but it actually has not a type defined (such as drawable, layout, id, string, etc). Hence the compiler error.

In fact, there is a cleaner version (found [here](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2219)):

```
<string name="email_ext">"@xyz.com"</string>
```

Using quotes looks less hacky

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use \uxxxx for special characters, this is the table of unicodes http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=0, in your case you can use \u0040 for @symbol something like this:

```
<string name="email_ext">\u0040xyz.com</string>
```

Regards!